# Best layout design for this application(tab bar with screen transition)?

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, transition, tabbar

I need to migrate an iOS App to android, and I'm new to Android, I'm not sure what is the best layout design for the app:

1. Tab bar(with buttons on it) always on bottom of screen
2. Each tab buttons corresponds to a screen, and each screen has a sub screen hierarchy

For example:
Tab Button: Shops
Screen shows: a list of shops
Click on a shop: transition to shop details with address, website etc
Click on address in shop detail screen: transition to map

Currently I have a TabActivity, each tab button is associated with an Activity for that button's function, inside each Activity, I have a ViewGroup that contains a fragment, so I can replace current fragment with new one for screen transition(I tried creating new Activity but the tab bar disappears). I don't know if this is the best way to design it, or is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is a `TabHost` to handle the different activities: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html

Check the tab layout example at the dev guide: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Using `Fragment`s will prevent you to deploy the app to any device < HoneyComb.

Comment: I am using TabHost, I just need different screens within one activity while keep the tab bar remain at the bottom, also, there is a compatibility package that allows apps with target 1.6+ using Fragment, goole "fragment android compatibility package" and you will know it.

Comment: I did not know about the compat package. To have more than one view on the same activity, take a look at `ViewFlipper` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html